# jQuery Multiple Slide Out Menu - Each Unique vs. Identical Siblings

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, jquery-animate, siblings

I'm trying to simplify my code by using .next() sibling rather than unique IDs for each slide out menu. However, I can't seem to get the code right when having each slide out menu the .next() sibling (click previous sibling to open menu container).

Ultimately, it will be easier to maintain just a single CSS class vs 6 - 8 different ones. I'm sure there is an elegant way to write the jQuery to get it to work... but I just can't get it. Any help is appreciated. Below is my jsfiddle (which includes my "unique" elements method for the slide out menus on the top row, and the "siblings" method on the second row) and the jQuery for the siblings method.

*edit: note that I'm looking to have only one menu out at a time. The top row does have some slide-out menus displaying simultaneously, but that's a specific circumstance.

http://jsfiddle.net/U3jHf/28/

```
$('.topIcon').click(function(){

    if($(this).next('.sideUITopIconContainer').is(':hidden')){  

            $(this).next('.sideUITopIconContainer').show();
            $(this).next('.sideUITopIconContainer').animate({'height':'456px'});
        $('sideUITopIconContainer').not(this).next('sideUITopIconContainer').animate({'height':'0'},function(){

                 $('sideUITopIconContainer').not(this).next('sideUITopIconContainer').hide();

        }); 
    }


    else{

        $(this).next('.sideUITopIconContainer').animate({'height':'0'}, function(){

                $(this).next('sideUITopIconContainer').hide();

        }); 
    }

});
```

Thanks in advance for any help.